# Wordpress gravity forms plugin not rendering correctly

Tags: wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

My form is not showing up on any page although it is there but hidden. I have included and there seems to be no JS conflicts or errors. No idea why the form is not displaying. The form preview works great thorough!

You can see the form page here: http://projects.wax.com.au/lioton/?page_id=14

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have conditional logic in your form? Anytime conditional logic is present the entire form is set to display: none; and then javascript is used to only show the fields that should be shown. If the display:none is not being removed, there's probably a problem with your theme. See this link for more details:

http://www.gravityhelp.com/question/why-is-there-a-style-attribute-of-displaynone-being-added-my-form-isnt-showing-up/

Comment: Correct - its a theme based issue but I'm not sure how to diagnose.

Comment: Do you have the code <?php wp_footer(); ?> in your footer.php file? This is where the Gravity Forms javascript to remove the display:none would be added. Without that, no javascript and therefore no form.